# Allocate memory failure

Tags: php

Working on a XML string variable, that normally occupies 1.4 Mb, happens to me that.

When is executed that part of the script:

```
echo memory_get_usage()." - ";
$aux_array['T3']=substr($xml, $array_min["T3"], strpos($xml, "</second>", $contador)-$array_min["T3"]);
print_r(memory_get_usage());
```

The display is

```
5059720 - 5059896
```

But when is that part:

```
echo memory_get_usage()." - ";
$aux_array['US']=substr($xml, $array_min["US"], strpos($xml, "</second>", $contador)-$array_min["US"]);
print_r(memory_get_usage());
```

the display is

```
5059896 - 6417152
```

To me, both orders are the same, but `memory_get_usage()` don't lie.

the exact output is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 1305035 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/devel/soap/index.php on line 138

Because a while sentence makes allocate that size many times.

Can you figure it out what's the problem?

Comment: _Ummmm,... what?_

Comment: Size of the script is irrelevant. You need to have enough memory to run it. This means your web server (apache, nginx, etc) needs to be able to run without hitting the dreaded OOM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are holding ~268MB of data in your PHP script, even though your input XML file is only 1.4MB big. Clear/remove variables you don't need anymore to clean up some memory while your PHP script is running. Or change the way you work with the XML file. Instead of loading the whole XML file at once you might want to use an [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/xmlreader) which walks over the XML nodes instead.